# If $a>0$, then find the minimum value of the expression $a^6+a^{-2} +a^3+a^{-4}+a^{-3} + 2^{6}$ is equal to m and holds for $a=k$, then....

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

> If $a>0$, then find the minimum value of the expression $a^6+a^{-2} +a^3+a^{-4}+a^{-3} + 2^{6}$ is equal to m and holds for $a=k$, then prove that $m=69$ for $a=1$

Applying AM GM inequality to the entire expression clearly gives its minimum value as 12.

I can see that the minimum value for the expression without the $2^6$ part is 5, and thus $m$ cant be equal to 12.

But i dont see how $m=69$ either. I mean it does obviously work with $a=1$, but I dont understand why it has to be 69. I dont know the methodical approach to solving this.

Edit: This was actually an MCQ, so I am no supposed to know that $k=1$. Otherwise it’s easy

Comment: If $a=1$ then $$a^6+a^{-2} +a^3+a^{-4}+a^{-3} + 2^{6}=1+1+1+1+1+1+64=??$$

Comment: Also, when $a >0$ you have $$a^6+a^{-2} +a^3+a^{-4}+a^{-3} + 2^{6} >2^6=64$$ so the minimum value cannot be $12$.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. You already figured out that the minimum value without the $2^6$ term is $5$. So the minimum value of the complete expression is $5 + 2^6 = 69$. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @MartinR I added more details about my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
By AM-GM
$$
a^6+a^{-2} +a^{-4} \geq 3 \\
a^3+a^{-3} \geq 2
$$

Comment: You could do all 5 terms with a single application of AM-GM.

Comment: @Kaind Yes, or even all 6: $$a^6+a^{-2} +a^3+a^{-4}+a^{-3} + 1+1+\ldots +1 \geq 69$$

Comment: @N.S. any reason why you didn’t take it 64 and instead split it into 1+1+1..

Comment: @Aditya Yes. If you try to apply AM-GM with 64, AM-GM gives you a lower bound which can be reached when $a^6=a^{-2}=a^3=a^{-4}=a^{-3}=64$, meaning NEVER. This tells you that the bound you get this way is NOT the minimum. To find the minimum you have to realise that to get equatlity in AM-GM you must have $a^6=a^{-2}=a^3=a^{-4}=a^{-3}$, meaning $a=1$, and if you want more terms, ALL extra terms must also be 1.... The key is that to get the minimum via AM-GM, equality MUST be possible.

Comment: So I suppose only a=1 is the only possible value here